# Why does my border radius only appear at the edge of the browser?

Tags: css, border-radius

https://faylette.github.io/3-column-preview-card-component-main/

I'm working on this and trying to apply a border radius to the containing element, and it does appear, but only when the element touches the edges of the browser. This occurs whether the flex-direction is row or column.

[border radius disappearing when not touching edge of browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbvcN.png)

[border radius appearing as desired when touching edge of browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xy4XR.png)

Here is the relevant CSS code.

```css
/* contains each of the containers (car cards) */
.content {
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

/* each car card */
.container {
    width: 350px;
    padding: 40px;
}

div#sedans {
    background-color: hsl(31, 77%, 52%);
}

div#suvs {
    background-color: hsl(184, 100%, 22%);
}

div#luxury {
    background-color: hsl(179, 100%, 13%);
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .content {
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 500px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="content">

    <div class="container" id="sedans">
      <img src="images/icon-sedans.svg">
      <h2>Sedans</h2>
      <p>
        Choose a sedan for its affordability and excellent fuel economy. Ideal for cruising in the city
        or on your next road trip.
      </p>
      <button class="btn1">Learn More</button>
    </div>

    <div class="container" id="suvs">
      <img src="images/icon-suvs.svg">
      <h2>SUVs</h2>
      <p>
        Take an SUV for its spacious interior, power, and versatility. Perfect for your next family vacation
        and off-road adventures.
      </p>
      <button class="btn2">Learn More</button>
    </div>

    <div class="container" id="luxury">
      <img src="images/icon-luxury.svg">
      <h2>Luxury</h2>
      <p>
        Cruise in the best car brands without the bloated prices. Enjoy the enhanced comfort of a luxury
        rental and arrive in style.
      </p>
      <button class="btn3">Learn More</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Please let me know how I can fix this and, as this is my first post on Stack Overflow, if I did anything wrong in asking this question. Thank you!

Comment: Please add reproducible code to your question, including relevant css and html

Comment: just to clarify. Your last card luxury doesn't have border on right side? thats the issue?

Comment: The container for the cards doesn't have a border radius on the right side when it touches the browser edge. So yes, the luxury card has no border radius when the container has flex-direction: row.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your container is rounded, not elements inside, you just see it as effect of `overflow:hidden;`. If your elements would always took 100% of parent (`.content`) width, then it will be fine.

What you can do is style first and last elements inside content:

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* font-family: 'Big Shoulders Display', cursive;
font-family: 'Lexend Deca', sans-serif; */

body {
    font-size: 15px;
}

/* contains each of the containers (car cards) */
.content {
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
    /* something wonky going on with the border-radius */
}

/* each car card */
.container {
    width: 350px;
    padding: 40px;
}

div#sedans {
    background-color: hsl(31, 77%, 52%);
}

div#suvs {
    background-color: hsl(184, 100%, 22%);
}

div#luxury {
    background-color: hsl(179, 100%, 13%);
}


h2 {
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 95%);
    font-family: 'Big Shoulders Display', cursive;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 30px;
}

p {
    font-family: 'Lexend Deca', sans-serif;
    color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.75);
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin-bottom: 75px;
}

button {
    background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 95%);
    border: 2px solid hsl(0, 0%, 95%);
    font-family: 'Lexend Deca', sans-serif;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

.btn1 {
    color:hsl(31, 77%, 52%);
}

.btn2 {
    color: hsl(184, 100%, 22%);
}

.btn3 {
    color: hsl(179, 100%, 13%);
}

button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 95%);
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .content {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}


/* ADDED CODE */
.content .container:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}


.content .container:last-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">

    <div class="container" id="sedans">
      <img src="images/icon-sedans.svg">
      <h2>Sedans</h2>
      <p>
        Choose a sedan for its affordability and excellent fuel economy. Ideal for cruising in the city
        or on your next road trip.
      </p>
      <button class="btn1">Learn More</button>
    </div>

    <div class="container" id="suvs">
      <img src="images/icon-suvs.svg">
      <h2>SUVs</h2>
      <p>
        Take an SUV for its spacious interior, power, and versatility. Perfect for your next family vacation
        and off-road adventures.
      </p>
      <button class="btn2">Learn More</button>
    </div>

    <div class="container" id="luxury">
      <img src="images/icon-luxury.svg">
      <h2>Luxury</h2>
      <p>
        Cruise in the best car brands without the bloated prices. Enjoy the enhanced comfort of a luxury
        rental and arrive in style.
      </p>
      <button class="btn3">Learn More</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="attribution">
    Challenge by <a href="https://www.frontendmentor.io?ref=challenge" target="_blank">Frontend Mentor</a>.
    Coded by <a href="#">Kitty</a>.
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to use `inline-flex` instead of `flex` on your `content`. Your problem is due to the fact that `content` element takes 100% width, but not your flex-items.

But when you resize your browser or in your words when element touches the edge , your flex container becomes smaller and `overflow:hidden` comes into effect, and your `border-radius` works as you expected.

So when you will use `inline-flex`, width of `content` will remain equal to width of your items.

**But this will cause other problems like element will overflow viewport etc, For that you can use use media queries for `content` to use flex instead of inline flex after certain width, which in you case is around 1300px.**

**Another Problem :**

I noticed that when width becomes less than 600px, then your individual container does not display border-radius propert for whicj you can do following:
Since you didn't apply border-radius to `content` but whole `container` itself, that's why individually they don't display `border-radius` property.
But if you add border-radius to `container` then it will loose its current form.

So what you can do is to use **Media Queries** and after certain width of page define/display border-radius for `container`.

After all this your code should function as follows:

```css
/* contains each of the containers (car cards) */
.content {
    display: inline-flex;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

/* each car card */
.container {
    width: 350px;
    padding: 40px;
}

div#sedans {
    background-color: hsl(31, 77%, 52%);
}

div#suvs {
    background-color: hsl(184, 100%, 22%);
}

div#luxury {
    background-color: hsl(179, 100%, 13%);
}
@media (max-width: 1300px){
    .content{
        display:flex;
        }
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .content {
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 500px;  
        gap:2px;
    }
    .container{
    border-radius:10px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="content">

    <div class="container" id="sedans">
      <img src="images/icon-sedans.svg">
      <h2>Sedans</h2>
      <p>
        Choose a sedan for its affordability and excellent fuel economy. Ideal for cruising in the city
        or on your next road trip.
      </p>
      <button class="btn1">Learn More</button>
    </div>

    <div class="container" id="suvs">
      <img src="images/icon-suvs.svg">
      <h2>SUVs</h2>
      <p>
        Take an SUV for its spacious interior, power, and versatility. Perfect for your next family vacation
        and off-road adventures.
      </p>
      <button class="btn2">Learn More</button>
    </div>

    <div class="container" id="luxury">
      <img src="images/icon-luxury.svg">
      <h2>Luxury</h2>
      <p>
        Cruise in the best car brands without the bloated prices. Enjoy the enhanced comfort of a luxury
        rental and arrive in style.
      </p>
      <button class="btn3">Learn More</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```